# Best practices for A/B testing?

Tags: customization

What do you guys use for A/B testing with WordPress?

Knowing that WordPress has plugins for everything, I went looking for A/B testing plugin and didn't find any.

It also looks like http://optimizely.com or similar solution may work together with WorpdPress. But I would much rather prefer managing everything in a single app.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a straight WordPress solution but I would recommend a/b testing feature found in the Google website optimizer. http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer/b/index.html.

It works with your analytics account. You just need to create two (or more) pages in WordPress.

Comment: Thanks PNMG, there is actually a plugin for GWO: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-website-optimizer-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can look at is the newly released MaxA/B plugin. It's free and we actively maintain it. Just keep in mind that it's for A/B split testing, not multivariate testing. You can grab it from http://maxfoundry.com/plugins/maxab.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is Automattic-funded [ShrimpTest](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shrimptest/) plugin, but sadly development seems stale.

Answer (score 0):

Also an plugin how [Shrimptest](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shrimptest/) is [A/B Theme Testing](http://wpplugins.com/plugin/11/ab-theme-testing-plugin), this plugin is not so early in development how Shrimptest, but i think, Shrimptest works fine.